# Best GUI maker to use for least memory overhead

Tags: python, c++, graphics

So I'm thinking of making a data visualizer with multiple tabs - my first task being to make correlations between all the variables (one tab).

I was thinking of doing this in wxPython and doing the calculations in Numpy/Scipy.

My question is, do you think it would be faster/utilize less resources to do this using Qt and C++? I would prefer to go with Numpy since it has significant optimizations that typically? make it better than naive C code.

Would it be possible to make the front end in Qt and write the backend in Python - if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know **exactly** what you need!

You should check out [PySide](http://www.pyside.org).

From the website: "*The PySide project provides LGPL-licensed Python bindings for the Qt cross-platform application and UI framework. PySide Qt bindings allow both free open source and proprietary software development and ultimately aim to support all of the platforms as Qt itself.*"

For tutorials on PySide, you can checkout the [PySide Documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySideDocumentation/) or the [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com) [tutorials on PySide](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/).

Comment: If you have any questions, please let me know. I use PySide on a regular basis. Good luck!

Comment: You're very welcome, my friend. Please feel free to come back and comment on here if any help is needed.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, just wondering if you know by chance the overhead that using Python bindings incurs.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf I doubt that using Python bindings for QT has any substantial overhead. Considering all the support applied to this project, I really would not worry about that until I discovered some real reason to worry. One thing to remember, though, is that Python is a slow language by nature and it is interpreted, so of course it won't run the same as something that is compiled to native...just something to think about. And plus there are optimizations that can be done.

Comment: can you elaborate on optimizations you would suggest / where I could find those - and do you mean python optimizations or python graphics optimizations as I know the former but not the latter.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf Yes, by optimizations, I mean optimizing your Python code and making it more efficient. You can check out the accepted answer to this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7165465/) for a more detailed explanation. You can also check out the [performance tips](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips/) on the [python.org wiki](http://wiki.python.org). Good luck! [:)].